# Custom form in home page of magento

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, forms

I created a custom form in homepage of magento as shown in this screenshot. 
[image: homeform]

I created new table `new_name_details` in magento DB, I want `name` and `age` to be stored in that table.
How to do it?

Comment: This question is appears to be too broad. If you want to achieve this, you need to create a module that has `Model` and `resources`

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of broad to fit it in one answer.
The idea is as this:
You need to [create a model](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics) that maps on your table.
Then [create a controller](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch) that handles the submit of your form.

In the action that handles the post request do this:

```
//read the post data
$name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('name');
$age = $this->getRequest()->getPost('age');
$model = Mage::getModel('namespace/module'); //instantiate the model you created
//set the values to the model
$model->setName($name);
$model->setAge($age);
//save the data
$model->save();
//add a success message
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Your submition...bla bla'));
//redirect to home
$this->_redirect('');
```

I hope this gives you a nudge in the right direction.